# Php call function from included file

Tags: php, class

I have a class and I am including the players.php file inside it.

```
class My_Class {    
    private $player_types;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->player_types = 'classic';
        require_once('players.php');
    }

    public function getPlayerTypes() {
        return $this->player_types;
    }
}

$mc = new My_Class();
```

How can I call getPlayerTypes function from players.php?

Also if its better to maybe use static method?

Comment: what type of code written in players.php?

Comment: I am asking that is php code is general script or it is based on OOP concept?

Comment: No, its not oop in players.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write :

```
$result = $this->getPlayerTypes();
echo $result;
```

inside the players.php. Definitely this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the **getPlayerTypes()** is a method defined in the class **My_Class**, if you want to call that method from ***players.php*** you should instantiate a new **My_Class** object in that file and call the **getPlayerTypes()** there.

```
//player.php
$mc = new My_Class();
$playerTypes = $mc->getPlayerTypes();
echo $playerTypes
```

and remove that

```
require_once('players.php');
```

from your class :)

Comment: My class needs to be instantiated in main.php file, so I cannot do this in players.php Also, when I try this $playerTypes = $mc->getPlayerTypes(); in player.php I get Undefined variable: mc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are instantiating the class with the variable `$mc`, you'd call the function using

```
$mc->getPlayerTypes();
```

Or you can assign a variable to the result,

```
$result = $mc->getPlayerTypes();
echo $result;
```

Comment: When I try this $mc->getPlayerTypes(); in player.php I get Undefined variable: mc